# How would I write a function which uses multiple if statements, where each statement would modify the word one after the other?

Tags: python, if-statement, nlp, lemmatization

I'm trying to write a function which would modify a tagged word depending on the tags present in the word, so basically a lemmatizer, but for words in Swedish.

For example if the word was tagged with A it would remove ending X from the word, and if the word also was tagged with B it would remove ending Y from the word etc. In total there are seven different endings that might be present in the word depending on the tag combinations and which I in that case want to remove.

What I've tried so far is to use several if statements after one another which would modify the word if it was tagged with one tag combination and then check if it was tagged with another tag combination and then modify it based on that and so on.

```
if tag1 == 'A':                                                   
    word = word.rstrip('x')
if tag2 == 'B' and tag3 == 'C' and tag4 == 'D':
    word = word.rstrip('y')
if tag3 == 'B' and tag4 == 'D':
    word = word.rstrip('z')
```

I'm having problems with understanding how I should phrase the if statements so that they would each check for a tag combination, modify the word if the statement is true and then pass the modified word along to the next statement. How would I do this?

EDIT: As Prune said, I know that I could just add if statements with all the possible tag combinations, but I wanted to see if there is a more elegant solution than to do that.

Comment: It seems like this code would do exactly what you want.  Have you tried it?  Does it work?  If not, what does it do instead?

Answer (score 1):

From your description, it seems that you know how to beat this to death with brute force, but you'd like something more elegant.  You might consider a structure of tags and associated removals, such as

```
rules = [ ['A',   'x'],
          ['BCD'. 'y'],
          ['B',   'z'],
          ...
        ]
```

Then iterate through your list of removal rules, applying each as appropriate, something like

```
for rule in rules:
    rule_tags = rule[0]
    # Check to see that all rule tags are in the input tags ... left to you to code
    if <your code here>:
        word = word.rstrip(rule[1])   # strip letter included in that rule
```

Does that get you moving toward a solution?

Comment: Yeah this seems like it would look a lot nicer than what I was originally planning to do. Do you think this system would affect performance more than the original one would?

Comment: Asking speculative questions is generally out of scope: run a timing test and see which works better in your environment.  How much human time is it worth spending to understand, debug, and maintain a more complicated system?